# IntelliJ IDEA Kotlin project what if there's no main class?

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea

Newbie question re IntelliJ IDEA project setup for Kotlin app :

Kotlin can have files that only contain functions - no Java Classes.

I create a new IntelliJ Project with a single Program.kt file with some functions, such as :

```
fun helloWorld() {
    println("Hello, World")
}
```

To run the code, I need to create a Run/Debug Configuration which requires specifying a Main Class.

If for Main Class I specify `ProgramKt` then on run I get an error :

> Warning: Class 'ProgramKt' not found in module 'Functions'

So how do I run my project ?

> IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2 (Community Edition) Build #IC-222.3345.118, built
> on July 25, 2022 Runtime version: 17.0.3+7-b469.32 amd64 VM: OpenJDK
> 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 11 10.0 GC: G1 Young
> Generation, G1 Old Generation Memory: 750M Cores: 16
>
> Kotlin: 222-1.7.10-release-334-IJ3345.118

EDIT :

Now I see how IDEA auto-creates entry-point `ProgramKt.class` in the `out` folder with some code to route to my `Program.kt` `fun Main(args : Array<String>)` ...

However if I add a package `pkg` and move my `Program.kt` into it, then IDEA Run/Debug Configuration can't find `pkg.ProgramKt` even though it definitely has been built :

`\out\production\Functions\pkg\PersonKt.class`

Here's the error :

> Warning: Class 'rsk.PersonKt' not found in module 'Functions'

Comment: perhaps try invalidating the caches?

Comment: The entry point to your program must be a function called `main()` taking either no params, or an array of strings. (Unless you're using some framework which does things differently.) That function can be inside a class (the ‘main class’), or at the top level (in which case the ‘main class’ is the one representing the file it's in, usually ending in `Kt`). You can't use any other function, because there's no way to tell the runtime which function to call, only which class.

Comment: Looks like IDEA auto-creates entry-point `ProgramKt.class` in the `out` folder structure with some code to invoke my `Program.kt` code `fun Main(args : Array<String>) { }`.

Comment: @JustSightseeing how to invalidate caches ?

Comment: @BaltoStar Kotlin is case-sensitive, so `Main()` ≠ `main()`. (So I'm fairly sure IntelliJ will be autocreating the latter.)

Comment: @gidds Any idea why IDEA Run/Debug Configuration can't find my `pkg.ProgramKt` even though I see `ProgramKt.class` has been built to the \out\production\Functions\pkg\ folder ?

Comment: Is it possible to share sample project?